# How to show text over an image and flow that text upward if it overflows?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout, css-grid

I am fetching a list of images and showing them in random height grid. I wanted to show some text over each image. Currently I am showing text by setting margin-top of text like :

```
<div className="item-author" style={{ marginTop: `${item.height - 65}px` }}>
 {item.author}
</div>
```

So, now there are two questions :

i. Is this correct way to display text over an image?

ii. How to overflow this text upwards? This text when it exceeds one line overflows to down which looks ugly?

Comment: Can you post a photo of how it looks now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with background-image

html

```
 <div class="back" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/659/200/300')" >

<p>Your text goes here</p>

</div>
```

css

```
   .back{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: none center/cover #f2f2f2;
    background-size: cover;

/*    tour required width height  */
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  /* Added flex to overflow the text bottom of the picture */
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-end;

}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/warar/pen/abojJGX)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nane. Yes. I have done till this. I want text to be on the bottom and when it overflows I want it to overflow in upward direction. so that it doesn't exceed the height of image container

Comment: I didn't  fully understand what is your requirement but i've updated the CSS code have a look

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked after little bit tweaks

Answer (score 0):

Create the same container but but a text class, in both the classes have a z-index where your text z-index should be higher

{item.author}